# TKinter: text widget doesn't update while program is runing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that uses finite element methods for calculations that can take up to a couple minutes.
Because the program might seem to have frozen for the user, I made it so that it calculates the number of iterations it'll make beforehand, and prints the progress in percentage to a text widget in TKinter.

The problem is that the main window freezes while the program is iterating, and only updates the text at the end, which isn't of much use for the user to know the current progress of the calculations.

Here's the specific part of the code:

```
progr+=dcompl
textbox.configure(state=NORMAL)
textbox.delete(1.0,2.0)
textbox.insert(1.0,"Processando... ")
textbox.insert(2.0,str(int(progr))+"%") #the variable progr is the current progress in %
textbox.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

It updates the "progr" variable each time it passes through a specific part of the code.

If I just print the "progr" variable to the console it works just fine, but I expect the user to be looking at the UI and not at the console.

Is there any way I can make the TKinter window not freeze and update the text while the program is running?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could import the `threading` module and run your number-crunching code in the background in a  separate `threading.Thread`,  or you could import the `subprocess` module and run it in an entirely separate process.  In your tkInter code, which must stay in the main thread, you would wait until the thread/subprocess sends you the signal that it's done and sends you the result.   (Remember not to access any tkInter objects from the background thread though: the tkInter toolkit is not thread-safe and this will cause sporadic crashes.)

In response to Bryan's comment:

How do you "wait" without tying up the CPU?   Some of my applications have used a simple loop containing a 1-millisecond `time.sleep()` and the resulting performance hit is not noticeable.  However, to do it properly you would probably want to use the tkinter object's `.after()` mechanism to repeatedly call a function that checks the status of your background number-crunching.

Comment: You never want to call `sleep` in the main thread of a GUI, because it will freeze the entire GUI while it is sleeping.

Comment: Thanks. I used the thread module to create a different thread and this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I just print the "progr" variable to the console it works just fine, but I expect the user to be looking at the UI and not at the console.

If you use a label instead of a text and update a Tkinter variable where you print, it should work fine.

```
def change_value():
    ## get the value because this program doesn't
    ## have a separate variable to use for the set()
    val=progr.get()  
    if val < 100:
        ## show that the same function can be called many times with updates
        textbox.after(50, change_value)
    progr.set(val+2)

top=Tk()
textbox=Label(top, text="Processando... ")
textbox.grid()

progr=IntVar()
progr.set(1)
Label(top, textvariable=progr).grid(row=1)

change_value()

top.mainloop()
```