# How to update Python Tkinter Text Widget with stdout during processes?

Tags: python, tkinter, stdout, updates

I have a Text widget that outputs stdout/stderr.  The problem is when I run a certain line of code (Paramiko - a SFTP file transfer), if stdout is in the console it updates just fine.  If the stdout is redirected to the Text widget, it doesn't print anything until it's already over.  I'm transferring 2+ GB files so rather than having it hang for a few minutes, I have a constant text output of % remaining.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724856/tkinter-text-widget-doesnt-update-while-program-is-runing) suggests using threading but I'd really like to avoid that since no other part of my program uses threads and I'd like to avoid that debugging.

Edit: Adding example.

```
class IORedirector(object):
    # A general class for redirecting I/O to this Text widget.
    def __init__(self, text_area):
        self.text_area = text_area

class StdoutRedirector(IORedirector):
    # A class for redirecting stdout to this Text widget.
    def write(self, str):
        self.text_area.insert(END, str)
        self.text_area.see(END)
```

Then during this print process, I use a callback like so:

```
self.sftp.put(localpath, filepath, callback=self.printTotals)

def printTotals(self, transferred, toBeTransferred):
    print "Transferred: {0}\tOut of: {1}".format(transferred,
        toBeTransferred)
```

Comment: how does your text widget output? Callbacks? How did you redirect? A minimal working example would be super helpful in this case :)

Comment: Added an example copied directly from source code.  Thanks for the heads up, not sure how I forgot to include it -_-